# WebStorm is not recognizing external library globals

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webstorm

I am working on a little project with AngularJS (`1.6.5`) in WebStorm. The problem here is that WebStorm is not recognizing any globals AngularJS defines. I have AngularJS installed and the right @types. I also defined AngularJS as an *External library* and I also made sure that AngularJS is not [excluded by WebStorm](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207024715-WebStorm-does-not-recognize-globals-from-other-packages-in-Meteor-project). Yet WebStorm is still giving me errors.

Example:

```
logConfig.$inject = ["$logProvider", "$compileProvider"];
function logConfig($logProvider: ng.ILogProvider, $compileProvider: ng.ICompileProvider) {
    // $logProvider.debugEnabled(false); //TODO add this in production
    // $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false); //TODO add this in production

    // Disable comment and class directives. Boosts the performance
    $compileProvider.commentDirectivesEnabled(false);
    $compileProvider.cssClassDirectivesEnabled(false);
}
```

The code above gets the following error in WebStorm: `Unresolved variable $inject`. (the `$inject` has a red color and the message is given when I hover over it)

Am I missing something?

---

**Update**

I may have found the problem. WebStorm doesn't reconsize AngularJS even though it is in my Node_modules, I have the correct typings (@types/angular) and I have registered as an exteral library (file-->settings-->languages & frameworks-->JavaScript-->Libra‌​ries).

When I type `import * as ng from "an|"`, and hit "ctrl + space" WebStorm doesn't give me any hints about the angular library. I am guessing these issues are connected.

Anyone knows if there is an other option to make WebStorm reconsize AngularJS?

Comment: Can you please show how logConfig is defined and how the IDE sees its definition when you do cmd-click on it. So far we had no luck reproducing the problem. All symbols defined like bar in foo.bar = [] are considered by the IDE as a new symbol.

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara, when I get home I will post the logConfig (where to find it?). I may have found the issue, but I don't know how to solve it. When I type "import * as ng from "angular"" WebStorm doesn't reconsize (doesn't give any hinting) about Angular. So it doesn't reconsize the library. It is in my node_module, aswell as the @types/angular. I also registered the library as an angular module in WebStorm (file-->settings-->languages&frameworks-->JavaScript-->Libraries)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point that you're working with the TypeScript code and not JavaScript code. For TypeScript the Libraries configuration is not applicable. Please make sure that you have a tsconfig.json file in your project. It is a requirement for any TypeScript projects.
Please also make sure that the TypeScript service is enabled in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to avoid confusion.  You can see that I've rolled back your edit. Check the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45018925/revisions). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem:

Like [Ekaterina Prigara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471674/ekaterina-prigara) said, somehow my TSLint was disabled. I needed to re-enable it via `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript | TSLint`. After I re-enabled it I restarted my WebStorm and got the error: Error: `Initialization error (typescript). Cannot read property 'createHash' of undefined`. I then removed my node_modules folder and reinstalled it via npm install. After that everything was working again.